# Is it safe to PHP SHA256 hash user submited content without vetting first?

Tags: php, hash, sha256

I want to allow users to submit input via `textarea` form submission and perform a SHA256 hash on the submitted text.  Is the hash susceptible to attack?  Should I "clean" the input before hashing?  And if so what's the best way to approach this? Is it enough to use `strip_tags` or can I convert the input by performing an `htmlspecialchars()` function on the string etc.

Code example would be

```
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>SHA256 on user input</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST' || empty($_POST['hashThis']) ):
    ?>
    <form name="user_data" method="POST" action="">
    <textarea name="hashThis"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
    <?
    else:
    echo hash('sha256', $_POST['hashThis']);
    endif;
    ?>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Just curious: why in the world would you hash a user's textarea input?

Comment: you do understand that hashing is one way... you can't take the resultant hash and get the user's input back.

Comment: Also stripping tags or encoding html entites is going to do exactly nothing as it pertains to viability of a hash

Comment: @kittykittybangbang, Thank you for your inputs.  I want to create a "fingerprint" of the users input.  So basically is a verification method to show (later on) that info is original because anyone can hash the same content at a later date and get the same hash.  But my question was, am I OK to not "injection check" the input since I am just going to hash the input?

Comment: @Orangepill, Thank you for your inputs.  I want to create a "fingerprint" of the users input.  So basically is a verification method to show (later on) that info is original because anyone can hash the same content at a later date and get the same hash.  But my question was, am I OK to not "injection check" the input since I am just going to hash the input?

Comment: The resultant hash may not be viable for a cryptographically secure key but it will work just peachy as a fingerprint, no need to alter the input in any way.

Comment: Note also that the hashes are going to match only if the content supplied is EXACTLY the same, an extra space in one on the inputs will make the two hashes totally different.

Comment: @Orangepill, thanks!!  That's what I thought but I wanted to be sure before I did something stupid!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as performing a hash is the *only* thing you are doing with the user's input, this is perfectly safe. You don't need to do any kind of preprocessing on data to make it safe to hash, and so long as you don't have raw output turned on (it's off by default), the output will be safe to print.

Comment: Thank you!!  I tried to vote you up, but it wouldn't take.  I don't think I have enough status to vote yet???